# iosslider: How can I stop image sliding getting paused when I put mouse on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, sliding

How can I stop image sliding getting paused when I put mouse on it. I want it to be continue running though I put mouse on any image.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a kickstart idea..

```
var paused = false;
$("#slidercontainer").hover(function() {
    var paused = true;
}, function() {
    var paused = false;
});
```

Write your sliding code below, with setInterval or what ever you wish

```
if(paused === false) {
 // keep your slide running
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sravis for your reply.
Now it works, we need to set autoSlideHoverPause to false that I forgot to change.
'autoSlideHoverPause': false,